# Create SQL View based on whether column values exist in another view

Tags: sql, filter, view

I currently have a SQL table and view, "JobTable" and "JobView" respectively.

I also have a second SQL table "JobOpTable"

The view "JobView" contains two key columns, "JobNumber" and "Status". This is a filtered view from the main JobTable that only shows Job Numbers where the status is "Ready for Operation".

The "JobOpTable" contains several operations against a single job number. For example,

JobTable:

```
JobNumber / Status 
A / Pending
B / Ready for Operation
C / Ready for Operation
D / Complete
```

JobView:

```
JobNumber / Status
B / Ready for Operation
C / Ready for Operation
```

JobOpTable

```
OpID / JobNumber / OperationNo / Data
001 / B / 1 / Some text
002 / B / 2 / Some text
003 / C / 1 / Some text
004 / D / 1 / some text
005 / D / 2 / some text
006 / D / 3 / some text
```

etc

I would like to create a view, "JobOpView", that filters the above to only show the rows that have JobNumbers in "JobView".

So based on the above data, the final view would show:

```
001 / B / 1 / Some text
002 / B / 2 / Some text
003 / C / 1 / Some text
```

i.e. filter out JobNumber "D" data that isn't in "JobView".

I'm not quite sure how to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: `JOIN`, `EXISTS`, and `IN` all come to mind.  What have you tried?

Comment: I think I might have it,

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have it,

```
SELECT dbo.JobOpTable*
FROM dbo.JobOpTable INNER JOIN dbo.JobView
ON dbo.JobOpTable.JobNumber = dbo.JobView.JobNumber
```